# Where can I check visa requirements online for free?

Tags: visas, online-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any online resource that can tell me what visa rules are for passport holders of a specific country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/is-there-any-online-resource-that-can-tell-me-what-visa-rules-are-for-passport-h)

One of the best resources for checking visa requirements online is through an IATA service called [Timaticweb](http://www.timaticweb.com/home.html). It's a subscription service and until recently it could be accessed through [Delta Airlines' passport and visa information page](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/planning-a-trip/international-travel/traveling-from-the-u-s.html). However, they have removed this option recently from their website.

Does any other website - airline or otherwise - offer free access to Timaticweb for checking visa requirements?