# Will I need a transit visa for transit in Stockholm in a trip from Turkey to Russia?

Tags: visas, airport-transfer

I have a flight from Istanbul (Turkey) to Saint Petersburg in Russia. I have two nationalities

I booked my ticket on my Syrian passport because I entered Turkey with it, and I will carry my Russian passport with me to enter Russia.

My flight is from Istanbul to Stockholm then after 3 hours I will change the plan to heading to Saint Petersburg.

Shall I need a transit visa for three hours in Stockholm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a transit visa in Zurich on the way to India?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21783/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-zurich-on-the-way-to-india)

Comment: @DJClayworth Citizenship and transit point are different, which could both impact the rules, how is that a duplicate?

Comment: @Relaxed The answer on that question points to a page which gives you all the information this questioner needs. In other words "this question already has an answer", even though the answer is to a slightly different question.

Comment: @DJClayworth Even if that were true, it's not the same question so it's not a duplicate, it's as simple as that. And the answer themselves are only concerned with Indian citizens. The document mentioned in the other question is from the Swiss federal ministry and does not contain all relevant information (i.e. the rules in other Schengen countries, which do differ, as explained in my answer below). At the end of the day, the conclusion is therefore only coincidentally the same.

Comment: If that's enough to consider the other question a duplicate, you might just as well point to any question about visas in Istanbul or Dubai and claim “a visa wasn't required either, that's all the OP needs to know” or “there is a link to Timatic”!

Comment: @Relaxed Have you looked at the 'standard answer' questions for UK, Canada and US Transit? Maybe we need something like that for Schengen.

Comment: @djclayworth Oh, but we have one, I devoted quite a bit of effort to it and this other question is not it. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area

Comment: Then why not close questions that are answered by it as duplicate? (no need to answer, we already got the 'take this to chat' warning)

Comment: @DJClayworth (If you don't want me to answer, don't ask questions) I don't care either way. I wrote the other Q&A to offer this possibility because I know some people feel very strongly about this but I don't mind more specific questions. Personally, I have occasionally voted for or against it but mostly simply abstain from voting or answering. What I do mind is closing questions by pretending they are duplicates when they really aren't. That's absurd no matter how you feel about the best way to handle visa questions.

Answer (score 5):

According to Timatic, you don't need a transit visa because you transit to another country:

> Visa required, except for  holders of a valid "D" visa issued by
>   another Schengen Member State For details, click here .  **TWOV (Transit
>   Without Visa): Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets
>   transiting**
>
> For details, click here on the same calendar day *Note: TWOV is not
>   possible when arriving from a non-Schengen Member State AND departing
>   to a Schengen Member State For details, click here

Comment: do you have a link for that quote?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to post a link to this page. You need to go to a website that provides Timatic information (see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/is-there-any-online-resource-that-can-tell-me-what-visa-rules-are-for-passport-h/1715#1715) and fill out a form.

Comment: Taken literally, the blurb you quoted is definitely incorrect. Citizens from at least 12 nations do require an airport transit visa in Stockholm, even if they are merely transiting and have an onward ticket. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area for explanations and authoritative sources. The answer should therefore specify that this only applies to citizens of a specific country (did you use Russia or Syria when filling in the form?)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a transit visa in Stockholm as either Russian or Syrian citizens so you can show either passport.

Sweden is part of the Schengen area and Syrians citizens do require an airport transit visa in many Schengen countries, but not Sweden. [Russian citizens flying from Turkey](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/annex_7b_atv-national_lists.en.pdf) also require an airport transit visa in France but can transit visa free everywhere else.

See also [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: I rewrote the answer to add more details but why the downvote?