# Russian transit Visa In Sweden

Tags: visas, transit, sweden, stockholm, russian-citizens

I'm going from St.Petersburg to Addis Ababa and I have a transit in Stockholm for 12 hours.

So does a Russian citizen need a transit visa to Sweden?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will I need a transit visa for transit in Stockholm in a trip from Turkey to Russia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19939/will-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-transit-in-stockholm-in-a-trip-from-turkey-to-rus)

Comment: yes but the asnwer is the same: you will arrive from non-schengen destination and you will departure to non-schengen destination, so you don't need a transit visa if your flights are on the same calendar day

Comment: Questions should be closed if the question is a duplicate and not if the answer happens to be the same.

Comment: some ppl are telling me that i do need a transit visa to sweden!

Comment: @Alex Which people and why?

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer from the Sweden embassy in Moscow:

> Welcome
>
> If you do not intend to leave the transit zone, then you do not need a visa.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> migration department
>
> Swedish Embassy in Moscow