# Do I need a transit visa in Zurich on the way to India?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, switzerland, zrh

I am travelling from US to India, with an Indian passport but expired F1 visa and going there to get my H1B visa stamping. I have a stop at Zurich for 2 hours while flying to India. Do I need a transit visa for my trip?

Comment: @Vince I thought so too at first but Karlson's answer to the previous question covers both cases and clearly addresses the OP's problem (and for bonus points, it's about the same nationality, which is very important). OTOH, Germany has additional restrictions for Indian citizens that do not apply in Switzerland. Maybe this question isn't an exact duplicate of either after all.

Answer (score 10):

If you stay within the international transit zone, then [you don't need a transit visa](https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/sem/en/data/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf.download.pdf/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf):

> Airline passengers on authorised regular services in principle do not
> require an airport transit visa providing they fulfill the following
> cumulative requirements:
>
> a. they are in possession of a valid and
> recognized travel document;
>
> b. they do not leave the transit area;
>
> c. they continue their journey by air within 48 hours;
>
> d. they are in possession of the travel documents and visa required for entering the
> country of destination;
>
> e. they possess an airline ticket for the journey to their destination;
>
> f. and they have booked their connecting flight prior to their arrival at a Swiss airport.

Here is link to page on FDFA: [Do I need an airport transit visa?](https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/india/en/home/visa/entry-ch/transit/do-i-need-an-airport-transit-visa.html)

Answer (score 4):

In case of those transiting Switzerland without leaving the airport international transfer zone, here are the countries that do require for its citizens to have airport transit visas: https://www.bfm.admin.ch/dam/data/bfm/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/vhb/vhb1-anh07a-d.pdf

This list is from Switzerland's FDFA -- the website of the Swiss Federal Office for Migration (enclosure no. 7A of the visa handbook 1).

Indian citizens DO NOT need a transit visa to pass through Switzerland if they do not leave the airport international transfer zone.

Comment: If you could quote the relevant information from that link it would be even better