# Is there a place to obtain "Visa requirements for X visa holders" or some such thing?

Tags: visas, online-resources

When looking up visa requirments, the Wikipedia pages for "Visa requirements for X citizens" and "Visa policy of Y" (where X is your country and Y is the country you want to visit) are quite useful. However, is there a place where consolidated information is provided about which countries allow certain other visa holders to enter without needing to get a separate visa? As an example, Romania is not currently part of the Schengen Area, but it does allow multiple-entry Schengen visa holders or residents of Schengen countries, regardless of nationality, to visit Romania for a limited time. Those who hold a valid US visa can also visit Mexico without an additional visa, for another example.

**Edit**: I've gotten another duplicate marking with the [Schengen question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders), so just to clarify: *this question is more generic*. It's asking for information or a place to obtain information regarding countries that allow certain visa holders to enter without an additional visa. An answer could of course refer to the answer of that question for information regarding what's available to *Schengen* visa holders.

Comment: That does answer the question about the Schengen visa, but there are other cases, such as Mexico allowing US visa holders to enter, @Traveller. As such I phrased this question more generically

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but are you aware of [IATA Travel Centre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/1767/1362), an interface to the Timatic database?  It doesn't give you a list of countries you can visit, but if you search destinations one by one, you can see if your visa status entitles you to entry privileges.

Comment: Reopened, but I do not think what you look for is available.

Answer (score 2):

A list of 40 countries that allow entry to holders of a **UK visa** is available here https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-countries-visa-free-with-uk-visa/ The list includes links to official sources.

From the same source as above, a list for **Canada** visa holders https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-20-countries-visa-free-with-canada-visa/, again with links to official sources.

A similar list for **Schengen visa** holders is available here https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/ *but* without any links to official sources.

And for **US** visa holders https://www.thomascook.in/blog/travel-to-multiple-countries-with-a-us-visa, again no links to official sources.

A country-specific search can be done on IATA Travel Centre https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ to confirm the information given about it on these sites is correct.